# How to pass environment variable & values to codebuild from Cloudwatch Event rules?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a CodeBuild buildspec which has command to run based on environments (reads Env. variable) eg: Dev, Test etc. I stead of creating two different codebuilds to run this command, I want to pass Env variable value from CloudWatch rules i.e. with Constant (Json).

I tried using the following but, nothing worked:

1. `{"name":"Env-var", "value":"valueFromCWatch"}`.
2. `{"name":"Env-var", "value":"valueFromCWatch", "type":"PLAINTEXT"}`
3. `{"environmentVariables":[{"name":"Env-var", "value":"valueFromCWatch"}]}`
4. `{"environmentVariables":[{"name":"Env-var","value":"valueFromCWatch","type":"PLAINTEXT"}]}`

Eg usage in BuildSpec:

```
- echo "Environment variable is: " `Env-var`
```

Is there a different way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CodeBuild targets support all the parameters allowed by [StartBuild](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/APIReference/API_StartBuild.html) API. You need to use [environmentVariablesOverride](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/APIReference/API_StartBuild.html#CodeBuild-StartBuild-request-environmentVariablesOverride) in your JSON string.

```
{"environmentVariablesOverride": [ 
     { 
         "name": "Envvar",
         "value": "valueFromCWatch"
      }
 ]}
```

Also, avoid using '-' in the environment name.